# E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call from JS: emulator can't open react native application

Tags: react-native, android-emulator

It used to open normally. throws error after shutdown
See screenshot
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtgAx.png

Comment: you're missing something in styles or somewhere in your code, probably you used ) instead of a :

Comment: otherwise show code for further help

Comment: but i not have any changes in my code and first time it worked well.

Comment: @chikabala already found the issue. it caused by version metro-react-native-babel-preset. upgrade to 0.66.2 and working well